# Join problem: 'is not sorted'

Tags: raspbian

Is there a bug in Raspbian `join` command? I can't get two files to join.

FILE1 left.cut:

`Level:
Reputation:
XP:
XP to Next Level:
Gold:
Diamonds:
Energy:`

FILE2 right.cut:

`111
154,955
722,642
911
1,225
0
1,500/1,500`

none of the following works:

`join left.cut right.cut
join left.cut right.cut > join.txt
join -j left.cut right.cut > join.txt
join -1 1 -2 1 -t"_" left.cut right.cut > join.txt`

I just want a simple line by line file join:

`Level: 111
Reputation: 154,955
XP: 722,642
XP to Next Level: 911
Gold: 1,225
Diamonds: 0
Energy: 1,500/1,500`

But `join` just about always errors on line 5 (sometimes on BOTH files), but always with FILE2 first. I have tried changed changing the spaces in FILE1 and the comma's in FILE2, but the error does not change, even if the line does.

I have verified the contents of the files with `hexdump -C`, that there are no hidden characters interfering.

I have used a "no option join" before with no problems, why is this not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the join 'man' page:

> For each pair of input **lines with identical join fields**, write a line to standard output. The default join field is the first, delimited by blanks.

So this will not work for your situation.
The command 'paste' should work, though. Try

`paste -d ' ' file1.cut file2.cut > join.txt`

The -d parameter changes the delimiter from a tab to a space.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the above (simple) answer.

If you dont have access to `paste` for what ever reason, the following will work:

`` for I in `seq 1 7`; do
  J=$(( $I - 1 ))
  echo "`cat left.cut | head -n $I | tail -n 1` `cat right.cut | head -n $I | tail -n 1`" >> join.txt
done ``

The `7` being the number of lines in each file.